# Python, virtualenv - Is it possible to use a single Pyramid project with multiple virtualenvs on different computers?

Tags: python, pylons, virtualenv, pyramid

I'm really interested in trying out the Pyramid Framework but only half of my programming time is spent on my computer here at home; I spend a considerable amount of time at school and use their computers as well, and according to the documentation for virtualenv, environments can't be moved around like projects.  What I'm thinking of doing is installing a different virtualenv for Pyramid projects on the computers I use at school in addition to one at home.  Would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `setup.py` file at the root of your project, you just have to list all the dependencies you have in `requires`.

Then, with your virtualenv activated, you run

```
python setup.py develop
```

This will install missing dependencies on your current virtualenv.

Example:

```
requires = ['pyramid',
            'WebError',
            'pymongo',
            'mock',
            'formencode']
```

Comment: So, does this do the same thing as pip install -r requirements.txt?

Comment: Yes, almost. `python setup.py develop` will also install your package for development (not just the dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use something like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) to keep your source file in sync between machines.
2. Use [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) in with virtualenv, keep a [requirements.txt](http://pip.openplans.org/requirement-format.html) file that lists all the dependencies for your software.

Answer (score 1):

this isn't really specific to pyramid. you need to look into version control. get a free account on github or bitbucket and push/pull your code from there.

Comment: Not sure, but I think here the problem is that a virtualenv cannot be moved to another folder.